# Wordpress - To an old version to new one > Media library disappear

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, media-library

I'm lost.
I've update an old version of Wordpress, for security reason, to the latest. Everything is working ! But... always a "but", all my media library in admin part has disappear, all images, all tags ...

Of course I googled it - I've redefined in wp-setting the folder, i've checked my htaccess, my settings (classified by dates/month) etc.

I have no idea anymore

Maybe you ?

Many thanks !
Ludovic

Comment: What version of WP were you using prior to the update? Are the images still present in the **uploads** folder and are the image records still present in the database?

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your answer. I as on 3.51 to the last 4.9 - Actually, the gallery on website still show the images, and of course, there still available on the FTP. I checked on PHPmyadmin, all records are presents